# Django generic CBVs passing variables from templates to views

Tags: django

I've been working on this forever and in spite of all the other questions/answers I can't figure it out. I can do this with FBVs but am trying to do it with CBVs.

I'm trying to create a list of boards on a webpage where clicking on each board would take you to that boards details. For example, in simple html:

```
<a href="board1.html">board 1</a>
<a href="board2.html">board 2</a>
```

However, I can't seem to get the urlconf to accept my url since I'm using a variable.
An excerpt of my template for listing the boards is in list_boards.html:

```
{% for board in all_my_boards %}
   <a href="{% url 'leaderboard:view_board' board.id %}">{{ board.title }}</a>
   <br>
{% endfor %}
```

The urlconf is:

```
 url(r'^view_board/?P(<board_id>\d+)/$', ViewBoardDetails.as_view(), name='view_board'),
```

and is included in the main urlconf by:

```
 url(r'^leaderboard/', include('leaderboard.urls', namespace='leaderboard')),
```

The board details are shown in the view as ViewBoardDetails:

```
class ViewBoardDetails(DetailView):
    model = LeaderBoard
    template_name = 'leaderboard/view_board.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        my_board_id = self.args[0]
        return render(request, 'leaderboard/view_board', {'my_board_id':my_board_id})
```

The error message I get is:

```
Reverse for 'view_board' with arguments '(1,)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'leaderboard/view_board/?P(<board_id>\\d+)/$']
```

Comment: Try use a keyword argument in your url: `{% url 'leaderboard:view_board' board_id=board.id %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my comment regarding keyword arguments - that shouldn't make a difference.

You have a mistake in your url. The regex group `board_id` has it's parenthesis in the wrong place. It should be:

```
url(r'^view_board/(?P<board_id>\d+)/$', ViewBoardDetails.as_view(), name='view_board'),
```

Hard to spot, but `?P(<board_id>\d+)` should be `(?P<board_id>\d+)`